# Why didn't Jon point out the white walkers when Dany showed up?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

[S07E06](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ6ayvGPP0g) ***Beyond the Wall***; This episode frustrated me:

When **Dany** showed up to save **Jon** and the others, why didn't he point out the walkers?

He already knew that killing them also kills their *"sired"* wights. Instead they waste time only killing wights when at least one could have been hunting the king and the other walkers.

I understand needing to make certain things happen for the plot line but at least make it believable. There is no way he wouldn't have signaled their position as soon as Dany and him made eye contact.

Comment: Plot armor. Good guys and bad guys have it now.

Comment: No white walkers, no season 8.

Comment: I think he was a bit too busy not getting killed.

Comment: Dany have nothing which can kill a White Walker and right now immediate danger is from wights which Dany can easily kill by fire.

Comment: `He already knew that killing them also kills their "sired" wights`: They know nothing Jon Snow. They are only speculating that, that was the case.

Answer (score 4):

Jon didn't tell her because he was too busy defending the rest of the group from the wights that were trying to get to them.

For all we know the rest of the group could have told Dany when they got on board with Drogon. The reason Drogon didn't attack the White Walkers is that he was likely too far away. So flying off to attack them would mean abandoning Jon, something which I'm sure Dany, and the rest of the group, doesn't want to do.

I can think of two reasons she didn't tell Rhaegal and Viserion:

1. She can't control them properly, she has a strong bond with them but she is only bound to Drogon so can't properly order them around.
2. They're off attacking wights and flying around. The odds are that they wouldn't have heard her anyway.

Another reason, though I'm not sure they know it, is that the White Walkers, or at least the Night King, can part fire near them. There is then reason to believe that the dragon fire wouldn't touch them at all.

---

OOU it would have made for a boring storyline and would end the main plot. Though we'd still have season 8 in the form of who wins the iron throne, I doubt it would keep as many people hooked as when the dead threat was still around.

Comment: To support your first point, Rhaegal and Viserion seem to mostly follow Drogon's lead, not Dany's. This could be resentment for chaining them in the dungeon or lack of a strong bond with Dany; but it could also just be a case of dragons following alpha males (similar to dogs and wolves). The Walkers shouldn't be able to resist dragonfire though, they are specifically said to be vulnerable to it (they are immune to normal fire, even though the wights are weak to both)

Comment: @Flater Dragons don't have Flock/Pack instinct, nor do they have Alpha males. Dragons, in the wild, live solitary lives like Grey Ghost, Cannibal and Sheepstealer did on Dragonstone. And [gender of Dragons is always changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43bW5.jpg). Dragons are however creatures of fire and blood and are attracted to battle like Carrion crows are attracted to corpses.

Comment: @Flater Has that been said in the show about the dragon fire? I can't remember it. I like your point about following Drogon too though it's also said that dragons like a good fight so it might have been a case of following just for that.

Comment: @Aegon: Gender of the dragons is irrelevant. I was not arguing that Rhaegal & Viserion follow Drogon because of gender. "Alpha male" is a widely understood term for the strongest being the leader of a group (Drogon). Furthermore, while dragons are not inherently pack animals, Dany's dragons have clearly shown to stick together as a family, and are not trying to live alone. My two cats (who are sisters) still do lots of things together, even though cats are not inherently pack animals. Familial ties are different from being in a pack, but "following the leader" can be appropriate in both cases.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: I'm not sure where I've heard it. Most likely, I heard it from either the show or Alt Shift X; and I consider both sources trustworthy. If the dragons followed because they wanted a fight (and apparently decided to follow Drogon out of their own free will), would they not have been present for Dany's attack on Jaime's caravan too?

Comment: @Flater Re: Jaime's caravan, [We did discuss it before](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78490/52541). The show is changing the whole dynamics defined by the author. Which gets people more and more confused by every episode. In the books at least, Drogon hunts alone and flies alone, often gone for weeks. The Other two were just chained. Before that, all three were carried around in cages. So there is no flock instinct thankfully in the books, which is consistent with TPATQ  prequel.

Comment: @Flater Good point and I doubt we'll get an answer for that. As far as I know we don't see Dany leave for the attack on the Caravans (if I'm remembering correctly) but the flight north all dragons are together. It could be explained that the other two were off somewhere else when Dany left for the first attack but followed for the second because they were around.

Comment: @Aegon: Regardless of the books and show being in line with each other or not, the **show** has shown the dragons share some activities (e.g. flying around Dragonstone), so it makes sense that they at least share _somewhat_ of a (familial or racial) bond. Your "they are attracted to battle" theory is disproven by their absence from the caravan attack (the attack and the rescue mission both happened in the show, again regardless of the books). You can't both argue evidence from the books, and also that the show strays too far from the books. The latter excludes the relevance of the former.

Comment: @Flater I am making an observation, not an argument mate, there's a difference. And attraction to battle is not my theory, but words of the creator of both books and show. ;)

Comment: Yes, he was fighting but they literally stared at each other for 5 seconds where he could have signalled. Like I said, I understand the need for things to happen in the plot but the way this went down just seemed so wrong. I can see the walkers being able to put out a small fire but not dragon fire. They are, after all made of ice and dragon fire isn't like normal fire, more of a napalm. Then again they aren't even really dragons, more like drakes since they only breathe fire, have no magical ability and only 2 legs.

Comment: @AdamCollingwood The stare was the usual dramatic, oh you came! For all we know they slowed time down to make it seem longer.